# Type error with React custom hooks in TypesScript

Tags: typescript, react-hooks

I'm trying to write a custom hook to provide an initial state via an API. The hook should, like `useState`, return both a `state` value and `setState` function. I'm still a bit new to TypeScript, and I've tried nearly every variant I can think of, but the compiler always complains about my `setState` function in particular.

```
function useRequest<A>(
    url: string,
    createErrMsg: (e: string) => string
): [A | null, SetStateAction<A | null>] {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get(url)
            .then(res => res.data)
            .then(setData)
            .catch(e => setErrors(createErrMsg(e)));
    }, [url, createErrMsg]);
    return [data, setData];
}
```

The problem evidently stems from the fact that I assign `null` as the initial state inside the hook. When I try to compile, I get an error, the final relevant line of which is `Type 'A' is not assignable to type '(prevState: null) => null'.ts(2322)` How can I rewrite my types (or function) so that this null doesn't cause me such a headache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Change your custom hook return type to this

```
[A | null, Dispatch<SetStateAction<A | null>>]
```

---

> Explanation:

`SetStateAction` is the type of `useEffect`

See:

```
function useState<S>(initialState: S | (() => S)): [S, Dispatch<SetStateAction<S>>];
```

where `S` is the type of state and `Dispatch<SetStateAction<S>>` goes for the set function

Comment: I'd already tried that!  But I get the following error: 
    `Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<A | null>>' is not assignable to type '(prevState: A | null) => A | null'.
    Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'A | null'.`

Comment: Actually, that was my mistake. The return type needed to be `Dispatch<SetStateAction<A | null>` not just `setStateAction<A | null>`